# Run ethtool after boot

Tags: debian, linux-mint, network-interface

I'm running lmde 2, and My net card doesn't seem to be able to work with my modem unless I set it to work with 10 mbps. Currently I'm using the command:

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 10 duplex full autoneg off
```

After each reboot of my computer. 
I would like to make this change permanent or run this command after every boot.

So my questions are:
How can I make this change permanent or alternatively, at what point in boot should I run the script and when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding:

```
ethtool -s eth0 speed 10 duplex full autoneg off
```

to rc.local before:

```
exit 0
```

did the trick.

---

my /etc/rc.local:

> #!/bin/sh -e
>
> ethtool -s eth0 speed 10 duplex full autoneg off
>
> exit 0